# Conditionally render title attribute of p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can we use facet inside a p:commandbutton so that we can change the `title` attribute of the command button depending on a backing bean property?

```
<p:commandButton id="btnSave" action="#{serviceController.saveSelected()}" ajax="false" >
    <f:facet name="title" >
         <h:outputLabel value="Save Details" rendered="#{serviceController.current.id eq null}" ></h:outputLabel>
         <h:outputLabel value="Update Details"  rendered="#{serviceController.current.id ne null}" ></h:outputLabel>
    </f:facet>
</p:commandButton>
```

But this is not working. It is like not giving any value to the value property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its even easier:

```
<p:commandButton value="#{serviceController.current.id eq null? 'Save Details' : 'Update Details'}"/>
```